# Unable to change the Terminal Services Configuration as DOMAIN Admin from local console?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, terminal-server, groups

how to make the necessary changes in

**tscc - [Terminal Services Configuration\Connections]
RDP-Tcp Properties | Client Settings tab**

Disable the following:
[v] **Clipboard mapping** (selected and disabled so I can't make changes)

how can I uncheck that option ? I'm logged in to the Terminal Server using the Enterprise\Admin but the option is still disabled ?

and I've double check from the AD GPO:

Setting Path:
**Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Terminal Services/Client/Server data redirection
Do not allow clipboard redirection  -  Disabled**

Is there anything that I should do to enable me to do the changes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the GPO setting to Not Configured. Then after a policy refresh you can set the setting from the server.

Comment: thaknsfor the reply Joe, which one "GPO setting to Not Configured" do you mean ? i set it to disabled as oppose to enable previously.

Comment: The GPO has disabled the setting and has disabled your ability to change it from the server. If you want to change the setting from the server you have to set the GPO to Not Configured so that the GPO is not controlling the setting.

Comment: ah... so the GPO setting can also disable the "[Terminal Services Configuration\Connections] RDP-Tcp Properties" I just knew that. many thakns for your response Joe.

Comment: Glad to help...